# Center Navigation in Wordpress Theme 'adamos'

Tags: wordpress, navigation, center

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong to center my navigation on desktop view.
I've used an existing wordpress theme called 'adamos', but then I noticed that the top menu wasn't exactly in the center, so now I'm having trouble fixing it.

If anyone could tell me what I'm overlooking or doing wrong, that would be great! :)

You can check the website [here](http://www.rockbandroomservice.be/wp)!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use an inline-block on the navigation instead of the float:left.